# KeyError: “likeCount" and IndexError: list index out of range in Python

Tags: python, jupyter, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client, keyerror

I am using Python jupyter notebook to get  stats like total likes count, dislikes count, total views for all the videos (~14k videos) for some particular you tube channel. I have used this code which I found in Gitbub.
I was able to run the code till last section
when I try to run below lines of code, I am getting the error message “KeyError: 'commentCount' “. Same with “likeCount”, “dislikeCount” etc..(Pls open the URL for error)

```
for i in range(len(allVideos)):
    i += 1
    title.append((allVideos[i])['snippet']['title'])
    publishedDate.append((allVideos[i])['snippet']['publishedAt'])
    video_description.append((allVideos[i])['snippet']['description'])
    liked.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['likeCount']))
    disliked.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['dislikeCount']))
    views.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['viewCount']))
    comment.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['commentCount']))
    videoid.append(allVideos[i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
```

[KeyError: 'commentCount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tb9ev.png)

I understand that this problem could be due to; when comments, likes and dislikes section disabled for some videos. How do I fix this problem ?

I  commented some of the above mentioned metrics line and reran the code. I ended up getting the below error message     “IndexError: list index out of range”

```
for i in range(len(allVideos)):
    i += 1
    title.append((allVideos[i])['snippet']['title'])
    #publishedDate.append((allVideos[i])['snippet']['publishedAt'])
    #video_description.append((allVideos[i])['snippet']['description'])
    #liked.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['likeCount']))
    #disliked.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['dislikeCount']))
    #views.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['viewCount']))
    #comment.append(int((stats[i])['statistics']['commentCount']))
    #videoid.append(allVideos[i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'])
```

[IndexError: list index out of range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yeQV.png)

Any smart people around who can help me with this. I tried different ways to fix it but unsuccessful ??

Comment: Why are you incrementing the counter `i` twice? Once in the loop itself (that's implicit in `for i in range(n)`) and once again in the loop body?

Comment: Hi I tried to remove the 'I' and re-run the code but the error remains the same. The exact code that I have used is here in this github link : https://github.com/ripulagrawal98/Analytic_Steps/blob/master/Extract-YouTube-ChannelData/ExtractInfo_YOUTUBE.ipynb

Comment: you could learn to use `for video in allVideos:` instead of `for i in range(len(allVideos))` and then code would be simpler and more readable. And you need number then you could use `for number, video in enumerate(allVideos):`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you get `list index out of range` because you use `i += 1`. You don't need it

Comment: if you get `“KeyError: 'commentCount' “.` then you should use `if 'commentCount' in stats[i]['statistics']: ... else: ...` to skip it when there is no key `commentCount`. Or you should use `get(key, default_value)` like `stats[i]['statistics']get("commentCount", 0)`

Comment: if you use some code from GitHub then ou could add link in question (not in comment) and then all people will see it.

Comment: Hi Furas, Appreciate your time on this query. I am still pretty new to Stackoverflow(Just created an account today). Taking sometime to frame the problem statement well.

Comment: Hi @furas, Appreciate your time on this query. I am still pretty new to Stackoverflow(Just created an account today). Taking sometime to frame the problem statement well. Also new to Python coding.  I used your below suggested code      
  'for video, stat in enumerate(allVideos, stats):

    v = video['snippet']

    title.append( v['title'] )
    publishedDate.append( v['publishedAt'] )

    s = stat['statistics']

    comment.append( s['commentCount'] )
    liked.append( s['likeCount'] )'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get `list index out of range` because you use `i += 1`. You don't need it.

You could also learn to use `for`-loop without `range(len(...))` like

```
for video in allVideos:
    title.append( video['snippet']['title'] )
    publishedDate.append( video['snippet']['publishedAt'] )
```

If you need number in `for`-loop then you can use `enumerate`

```
for number, video in enumerate(allVideos):
    title.append( video['snippet']['title'] )
    publishedDate.append( video['snippet']['publishedAt'] )

    comment.append( int(stats[number]['statistics']['commentCount']) )
    liked.append( int(stats[number]['statistics']['likeCount']) )
```

but in your code you could do it simpler with `zip()`

```
for video, stat in zip(allVideos, stats):
    title.append( video['snippet']['title'] )
    publishedDate.append( video['snippet']['publishedAt'] )

    comment.append( int(stat['statistics']['commentCount']) )
    liked.append( int(stat['statistics']['likeCount']) )
```

You could make it even more readable if you first get `['snippet']` and `['statistics']` and assign to variables

```
for video, stat in zip(allVideos, stats):

    v = video['snippet']

    title.append( v['title'] )
    publishedDate.append( v['publishedAt'] )

    s = stat['statistics']

    comment.append( int(s['commentCount']) )
    liked.append( int(s['likeCount']) )
```

---

If you get KeyError then you should use `if/else`

```
    s = stat['statistics']

    if 'commentCount' in s:
        comment.append( int(s['commentCount']) )
    else:
        comment.append( 0 )

    if 'likeCount' in s:
        liked.append( int(s['likeCount']) )
    else:
        liked.append( 0 )
```

or shorter using `.get(key, default value)`

```
    s = stat['statistics']

    comment.append( int(s.get('commentCount', 0)) )
    liked.append( int(s.get('likeCount', 0)) )
```

---

Full version:

```
for video, stat in zip(allVideos, stats):

    v = video['snippet']

    title.append( v['title'] )
    publishedDate.append( v['publishedAt'] )
    video_description.append( v['description'] )
    videoid.append( v['resourceId']['videoId'] )

    s = stat['statistics']

    liked.append( int(s.get('likeCount',0)) )
    disliked.append( int(s.get('dislikeCount',0)) )
    views.append( int(s.get('viewCount',0)) )
    comment.append( int(s.get('commentCount',0)) )
```

but if you want to add it to DataFrame then you could make it simpler without all these lists `title`, etc.

```
all_rows = []

for video, stat in zip(allVideos, stats):

    v = video['snippet']
    s = stat['statistics']

    row = [
        v['title'],
        v['resourceId']['videoId'],
        v['description'],
        v['publishedAt'],
   
        int(s.get('likeCount',0)),
        int(s.get('dislikeCount',0)),
        int(s.get('viewCount',0)),
        int(s.get('commentCount',0)),
    ]

    all_rows.append(row)

# - after `for`-loop -

df = pd.DataFrame(
         all_rows, 
         columns=['title', 'videoIDS', 'video_description', 'publishedDate', 'likes', 'dislikes', 'views', 'comment']
     )
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full working code:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pandas as pd

youTubeApiKey = "AIzaSy..."
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=youTubeApiKey)

snippets = youtube.search().list(part="snippet", type="channel", q="nptelhrd").execute()
print('len(snippets):', len(snippets))

channel_id = snippets['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']
print('channel_id:', channel_id)

stats = youtube.channels().list(part="statistics", id = channel_id).execute()
print('len(stats):', len(stats))

#status = youtube.channels().list(id=channel_id, part='status').execute()
#print('len(status):', len(status))

content = youtube.channels().list(id=channel_id, part='contentDetails').execute()
print('len(content):', len(content))

upload_id = content['items'][0]['contentDetails']['relatedPlaylists']['uploads']
print('upload_id:', upload_id)

all_videos = []
next_page_token = None
number = 0
while True:
    number +=1 
    print('page', number)
    res = youtube.playlistItems().list(playlistId=upload_id, maxResults=50, part='snippet', pageToken=next_page_token).execute()
    all_videos += res['items']

    next_page_token = res.get('nextPageToken')

    if next_page_token is None:
        break
print('len(all_videos):', len(all_videos))

video_ids = list(map(lambda x: x['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId'], all_videos))
print('len(video_ids):', len(video_ids))

stats = []
for i in range(0, len(video_ids), 40):
  res = youtube.videos().list(id=','.join(video_ids[i:i+40]), part='statistics').execute()
  stats += res['items']
print('len(stats):', len(stats))

all_rows = []

number = 0
for video, stat in zip(all_videos, stats):
    number +=1 
    print('row', number)

    v = video['snippet']
    s = stat['statistics']

    row = [
        v['title'],
        v['resourceId']['videoId'],
        v['description'],
        v['publishedAt'],
   
        int(s.get('likeCount',0)),
        int(s.get('dislikeCount',0)),
        int(s.get('viewCount',0)),
        int(s.get('commentCount',0)),
    ]

    all_rows.append(row)

# - after `for`-loop -

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=['title', 'videoIDS', 'video_description', 'publishedDate', 'likes', 'dislikes', 'views', 'comment'])

print(df.head())
```

Result:

```
                                               title     videoIDS  ... views comment
0  NPTEL Awareness workshop in association with P...  TCMQ2NEEiRo  ...  7282       0
1                            Cayley-Hamilton theorem  WROFJ15hk00  ...  3308       4
2  Recap of matrix norms and Levy-Desplanques the...  WsO_s8dNfVI  ...   675       1
3                  Convergent matrices, Banach lemma  PVGeabmeLDQ  ...   676       2
4                  Schur's triangularization theorem  UbDwzSnS0Y0  ...   436       0

[5 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: below is the error message I am getting  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
??TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-9ecca9b8b232> in <module>
----> 1 for video, stat in enumerate(allVideos, stats):
      2 
      3     v = video['snippet']
      4 
      5     title.append( v['title'] )

TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: there was mistake - it should be `zip()` instead of `enumerate()`

Comment: Would it be possible for you provide the complete code for the section i mentioned in the earlier ... I will run the same code and test it

Comment: Meanwhile I was creating full working code and now this code is in answer.

Comment: WoW  WOW and WOW... you are simply outstanding and this code is much more efficient...This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to give rating for the solution...Obviously 5stars for the quick turn around.. Thanks again and have a great day ahead

Comment: The code has been working great for me. Wanted to check with you if there is a way to pull the "video duration". Also, Can I pull data for particular data range, say last 6 months. Thanks again for your support on this